# Sentence structure of いつだって不安な朝は迎え難い　今日くらい大丈夫だって言って

Tags: translation, particles

What is the sentence structure of this sentence, which is from the lyrics of [this song](http://www.kget.jp/lyric/140920/%E5%90%8D%E5%89%8D_%E7%9F%A2%E9%87%8E%E7%9C%9F%E7%B4%80)? I'm lost. How to understand くらい?

> いつだって不安な朝は迎え難い　今日くらい大丈夫だって言って

Does the sentence mean: Mornings of anxiety are always difficult to deal with, please tell me even something like 'things will be fine today'.

I'm not sure. Please kindly help.

Comment: Thank you Chocolate! So the narrator is actually requesting the addressee to do all these things:「気づいてよ」「ここに来て」「大丈夫だって言って」「耳を澄まして」「満たして」?

Answer (score 2):

I think "くらい" in this case suggests that the other person usually doesn't say the word "大丈夫". So the meaning would be like: please tell me 'things will be fine' at least today (because today is a special day, or you haven't said that in a while, or something like that.)

date + くらい[は] is a common phrase. You can say for example "テストの前日くらいは勉強しなさい" or "誕生日くらいおいしいものを食べよう".